# To Verify a mock, is a return required to verify

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am having trouble getting my Verify to work on a DB call.

I have a method that I am simply trying to verify that a database call was made.

I can't post the real code but here is a close example.

```
    protected void ReportDB(uint waitTimeInMinutes)
    {
        //check database connection
        Status dbStatus = Status.Ok;
        string dbComment = "ok";
        try
        {
            Data.GetActive("1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dbComment = "Unable to access the database: " + ex.Message;
            dbStatus = Status.Critical;
        }

        //Report Status.
    }
```

So basically the GetActive() method just makes a database call. If it doesn't throw an exception then we are good and connectivity is up.

My test method is.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReportDBStatusTest()
    {
        _fakeData.Setup(s => s.Data.GetActive(It.IsAny<string>()));

        _unitUnderTest = new Service();
        _unitUnderTest.ReportDB(0);

        _fakeData.Verify(s => s.Data.GetActive(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
    }
```

I debug through and the method is called and everything, yet the verify says it was called Times.Never.  I think I may just be misunderstanding how to do this correctly.

Error:

Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: s => s.Data.GetActive(It.IsAny())
Configured setups and invocations:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is expected. This is because the 'Data' object inside the 'ReportDB' object is not the same as the 'Data' object inside the '_fakeData' object.

One workaround would be to externalize the 'Data' object in your 'ReportDB' object so that it can be mocked. Else, you need to alter your unit test.